# Javascript Form and Firebug error

Tags: javascript, forms, function, local-storage

I am trying to get the data entered into the fields to be input into a form.  However, upon hitting save, nothing happens.  When I ran it in firefox, however, the console gave me the error:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments, for         
var Name    = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
```

Here is the `Html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Input Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <h2>Please enter your information</h2>
            <form id="Form1" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputName">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputMovie">Favorite Movie</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMovie" placeholder="Favorite Movie">
                </div>
                <button id="save" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <h2>Dataset</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Datainput.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the `js` code

```
var save = document.getElementById("save");

save.onclick = function(){
    var Name    = document.getElementById("inputName").value;
    var Email   = document.getElementById("inputEmail").value;
    var Movie   = document.getElementById("inputMovie").value;

    var Form1 = new Form(Name, Email, Movie);   


};

function Form(Name, Email, Movie){
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Email = Email;
    this.Movie = Movie;
    console.log(Name);
    console.log(Email);
    console.log(Movie);
}
```

I  need to write the data to a page, store it, and clear local storage.
However, I cannot move on until I figure out why the code I have is not running correctly

Comment: are you really sure? Cant reproduce your problem.

Comment: what happens when you try to run it?

Comment: All data will printed out on the console

Comment: what did you run it in? as absolutely nothing happens on my end

Comment: Tryed in 3 Browsers (`Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Opera`): http://abload.de/img/unbenannt7csy7.png only have include the JS-Part directly in the HTML and the button has become an `type="button"` to prevent the form submit

Comment: im not sure, but check out your file encoding.

Comment: I actually got it to print out on the console by adding a prototype.

Comment: I appreciate your input

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could get this information to appear on a new page?

Comment: no sorry. Can you tell me the exact browserversion? What did u mean with 'appear on new page'

Comment: Excuse me that's not exactly what I meant, I need to add the information to a list visible on the page.

Comment: On the database? Do you mean the data handling after press the Button?

Comment: I mean that upon pressing the save button the information will be sorted into a list on the page

Comment: http://gyazo.com/77c5fdf9931061a06341d30d68854a60
for example

Comment: Ah, you would like to create an Address Book? You would add it over Javascript in an `ul/li`? The simplest way is to use a JS-Lib like `jQuery`. I create a little fiddle.

Comment: Not exactly, the address book is just an example.  I would like to take the data that is inputed from the original code and html I provided, and put that into a list that looks similar to the address book example.
I just would like to know if you have any tips for me to take what I have and make is so that its made into a list

Comment: how could I use for example element.innerHTML to do such a thing

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpD49/1/